# magento 2 installation error while installing on server

Tags: extensions, error, installation, magento-2.0

While I was installing Magento 2 on my live server I got following error:

PHP Extensions Check 2 missing PHP extensions: PHP Extension xsl and PHP Extension zip.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install these extensions in PHP.

How to do this on Ubuntu you can find in [Magento2 Developers Documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html)

If you install on Windows, feel free to look into PHP Documentation [how to install extensions on Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php)

Comment: Hello sir, i uploaded magento files directly on server at my subdomain and then run the setup url so how do i apply those steps in my subdomain

Comment: then it's better contact to server administrator to install additional extensions